# Mix of the 2nd and the 1st Conditional

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

> If she got back late last night, she won't come to school today.

Is it grammatically OK? It sounds right, but I couldn't find any reference to a conditional sentence that has Past Simple in the if-clause and Future Simple in the main clause. When it comes to mixed conditionals, I know only of the 3-2 and the 2-3 mixes.

Comment: What is the 3-2 and 2-3 mixes??

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh If I were less busy, I would have visited yesterday's party. (2-3), If I had graduated from a medical school, I would be a doctor now (3-2). 

[link](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/mixed-conditional/)

Comment: It looks fine to me.